# Первый элемент массива всегда получается пустым

Tags: jquery, массивы

Есть такая функция:

```
var getInfoForPrices = function (arg) {

var dateIn = $(".date-in").val();
var dateOut = $(".date-out").val();
var roomsId = $('.collect-date .rooms-id').val();
var roomsCount = $('.collect-date .rooms-count').val();
var roomsIdArray = roomsId.split(",");
var roomsCountArray = roomsCount.split(",");

$('.collect-date .start-date').val(dateIn);
$('.collect-date .end-date').val(dateOut);

if (arg.hasClass('room-count')) {
    var currentRoomId = arg.attr('id').split('-')[1];
    var currentRoomCount = arg.find('option:selected').val();

    if($.inArray(currentRoomId, roomsIdArray) === -1){
        roomsIdArray.push(currentRoomId);
        roomsCountArray.push(currentRoomCount);
    }
    else {
        var elPos = $.inArray(currentRoomId, roomsIdArray);
        roomsCountArray[elPos] = currentRoomCount;
    }

    $('.collect-date .rooms-id').val(roomsIdArray);
    $('.collect-date .rooms-count').val(roomsCountArray);
}
};
```

которая служит для того, чтобы собрать данные и подставить их в скрытые поля. Функция вызывается при изменении нескольких полей в другой форме:

```
$(".date-in, .date-out, .room-count").change(function () {
    getInfoForPrices($(this));
});
```

Но при этом получается, что первые элементы массивов каждый раз оказываются пустыми

[image]

Как сделать так, чтобы в массив не заносился первый пустой элемент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, сделано так

```
var getInfoForPrices = function (arg) {

var dateIn = $(".date-in").val();
var dateOut = $(".date-out").val();
$('.collect-date .start-date').val(dateIn);
$('.collect-date .end-date').val(dateOut);

if (arg.hasClass('room-count')) {
    var roomsId = $('.collect-date .rooms-id').val();
    var roomsCount = $('.collect-date .rooms-count').val();
    var roomsIdArray = [];
    if (roomsId.length > 0) {
        roomsIdArray = roomsId.split(",");
    }
    var roomsCountArray = [];
    if (roomsCount.length > 0) {
        roomsCountArray = roomsCount.split(",");
    }

    var currentRoomId = arg.attr('id').split('-')[1];
    var currentRoomCount = arg.find('option:selected').val();

    if($.inArray(currentRoomId, roomsIdArray) === -1){
        roomsIdArray.push(currentRoomId);
        roomsCountArray.push(currentRoomCount);
    }
    else {
        var elPos = $.inArray(currentRoomId, roomsIdArray);
        roomsCountArray[elPos] = currentRoomCount;
    }

    $('.collect-date .rooms-id').val(roomsIdArray);
    $('.collect-date .rooms-count').val(roomsCountArray);
}
};
```

Comment: Нууу. Еще и заминусовали. Лучше бы объяснили как правильно надо сделать.

Comment: Заминусовали за плохой ответ. Сами задали вопрос, сами же на него ответили плохо: без объяснения что было сделано и что не работало. Бесполезный вопрос-ответ.

Comment: что не работало, было подробно написано в изначальном вопросе. по ответу: по коду недостаточно очевидно, что было сделано? тут все-таки не такая уж длинная простыня, чтобы было сложно увидеть, что изменилось.